# Variable undefined after setting interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, setinterval

I'm wondering why my variable, which is initially set to a value, becomes `undefined` when accessed from an `interval`.

Consider the following **JQuery**:

```
var TEST = {
    DIR: null,
    ITV: null,

    Init: function () {
        this.DIR = 1;
        this.Action();
    },

    Action: function () {
        console.log(this.DIR);
        if (this.ITV == null)
            this.ITV = setInterval(this.Action, 1000);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    TEST.Init();
});
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
1
undefined
```

I understand the `1`, because the value of `TEST.DIR` is set to `1` inside the `Init` function, which it still is when the `Action` function is called for the first time.

However, when this function is being called for the second and all other times from the `interval TEST.ITV`, `TEST.DIR` is `undefined` and I don't understand why.

See also this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h44y81Lu/)**.

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.Action` is passed to `setInterval` as function w/o its context so `this` is not pointing to the instance of `TEST` any more but defaults to `window`. Try it like this:

```
var TEST = {
    DIR: null,
    ITV: null,

    Init: function () {
        this.DIR = 1;
        this.Action();
    },

    Action: function () {
        console.log(this.DIR);
        if (this.ITV == null)
            this.ITV = setInterval(function() {TEST.Action() }, 1000);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    TEST.Init();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h44y81Lu/4/

Comment: Of course! I knew I was overlooking something. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

thats because 'this' refers to the window in your set interval, thats why its undefined (there is no window.DIR)

A lot of people have issues with the 'this' keyword, check the [MDN docs out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)